# Bundle install Windows Custom Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, bundler, jruby

I'm quite new to Ruby and I am working on a project that runs well on linux, but I need to use Windows for it. I´m using jruby and I need to install a gem from a custom source. (A modification of activerecord-jdbc-adapter from a git source). The issue comes when I run bundle install and it tries to install this gem, because after it compiles it gives me this error:

```
SystemCallError: Unknown error - Unknown Error (20047) -
C:\jruby-9.0.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\shared\bundler\gems\activerecord-rails-adapter-90bbc7afe6eb\C:
An error occurred while installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.4.0.dev), and
```

Bundler cannot continue.

In linux, it creates the folder home/admin/.... but in windows it starts on C:
I think it´s trying to create a directory with the name C: but the name C: is not allowed as name for a directory, because : is an invalid character. Maybe there is a way to avoid the creation of (or change the name of) that folder, but I have search and I can not find anything about this error.

I will appreciate your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: the possibility to use AR-JDBC from a `:git` source is not that much tested - pretty much no official blessing at this point. it will attempt to compile the native extension using `javac`. recommend you try this using latest JRuby (9.1.5.0) on Windows and confirm the behaviour in which case it may be reported for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution searching for other clues. Maybe is not the correct way to resolve it, but it made me be able to finish installing that Gem. In C:\jruby9.0.1.1\lib\ruby\stdlib\jars\installer.rb, i went to the line 168 in the method do_install( vendor, write_require_file ) and changed this:

```
def do_install( vendor, write_require_file )
  vendor_dir = File.join( @mvn.basedir, spec.require_path )
  jars_file = File.join( vendor_dir, "#{spec.name}_jars.rb" )

  # write out new jars_file it write_require_file is true or
```

To this:

```
def do_install( vendor, write_require_file )
  vendor_dir = File.join( @mvn.basedir, spec.require_path.gsub(':','') )
  jars_file = File.join( vendor_dir, "#{spec.name}_jars.rb" )

  # write out new jars_file it write_require_file is true or
```

So it removes the colon (:) from the folder it is tryng to create on install time. This caused the bundler to be able to finish installing the gem. Maybe it is the real solution and it resolves a bug in jruby for windows, or maybe not, but for now I resolved my problem. Thank you for the help!!